# Acceleo generator doesn't find applied stereotypes when processing submodel unit from Papyrus

Tags: maven, acceleo, papyrus

I'm using Acceleo in stand alone mode to generate source code from UML model (edited with Papyrus).

I followed this tutorial https://wiki.eclipse.org/Acceleo/Maven (using same versions).

I created my own uml profile and applied some stereotypes on some elements (Class, Package, ...), all work very well...

But when I use the "submodel unit" feature from Papyrus to "split" uml files, Acceleo can't retrieve applied stereotypes on elements from "submodel" files (it still find them on the "root" file).

When I reintegrate all splitted file, all work like a charm again.

I can't figure out what is wrong, any idea ?

**Update :** I provided a minimal example (but following global structure) here : http://www.wikiupload.com/D0NI4YR6T9KNCC7.
Simply run

```
mvn clean install
```

On root "example" dir. Results are in "example/result/target/result" dir

Comment: can you provide an example how did you do it? it'll help guys who will try to answer your question

Comment: I provided a complete (but minimal) example